# How to store JSON string in MySQL db

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm storing JSON data in a MySQL table using the code below. It works fine if the JSON is short but breaks for longer text. The "field_json" is a LONGTEXT.

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE mytable 
    SET field_json = '$json_string'
    WHERE id = $userid");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'G
>   '","username":"C0WB0Y","lastName":"","id":31874363},{"pathToPhoto":"22960/phot'
>   at line 2

Comment: Please, please, please consider using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php).  Well, only if you prefer your site un-hacked ...

Comment: Just as a side node, if you are storing JSON in a mysql table, maybe you should consider using a database that is better suited to store such data like CouchDB, MongoDB, etc

Comment: good point. This is just for an import job where I want to save the json in case I have to process it again

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use place holders otherwise you are susceptible to SQL injection: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Otherwise, here's a quick fix: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
$sql = sprintf(
        "UPDATE mytable SET field_json = '%s' WHERE id = '%s'",
        mysql_real_escape_string($json_string),
        mysql_real_escape_string($userid)
);
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

## EDIT

Please use PDO ( http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php ). The `mysql` extension has been deprecated as of 5.5

Comment: SQL Injection possible with `$userid`. You can use `(int) $userid` instead of mysql_real_escape_string.

Comment: The question doesn't specify the data type for the id field, but in systems i've worked on, the user id is a uuid, not an int.

Answer (score 4):

Escape the JSON string:

```
$json_string = mysql_real_escape_string( $json_string);

$sql = sprintf("UPDATE mytable 
    SET field_json = '$json_string'
    WHERE id = $userid");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: in your example, $userid could cause an SQL injection.

Comment: It could, but not only do we not know where `$userid` is coming from, it's also not the source of the OPs problem.

Comment: While not OP problem, the provided example silently leaves a potential security problem.

Comment: thanks. Good points about the security. It's an import job so security isn't an issue .

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the quotes in your JSON string - otherwise they terminate the SQL-Query resulting in the exception you got.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    $json_string = mysql_real_escape_string( $json_string );
    $sql = sprintf("UPDATE mytable 
    SET field_json = '$json_string'
    WHERE id = $userid");
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Comment: SQL Injection possible with $userid