# How to insert JSON values into MySQL using PHP for an API creation?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following JSON values:

```
[newcomposeMail={"msg":"test mail","senderUserId":"1006","subject":"test","to":"10002"}, composeMail]
```

My query is:

```
 INSERT INTO `push_msg_table`(`pid`, `subject`, `msg`, `sentuserid`, `sent_time`, `upload_path`, `status`) VALUES()
```

I need to insert these values to the mysql table. I am new to JSON.

Comment: use json_decode(newcomposeMail) and try

Comment: possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8990762/how-to-store-json-string-in-mysql-db

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in php

```
json_decode(newComposeemail,true);
```

Adding true you will get proper Array else it will return Object in php

If there are multiple entries in json , then you will have to loop through the json array, in order to insert multiple entries in DB

Answer (score 0):

Make sure firstly that you are getting all json values in php by request array or json_decode function.

Then after you get all the values which will come in the form of strings, so the string values which are integer should be converted into integer only then the INSERT query will work. So the query will be like this.

```
INSERT INTO push_msg_table(pid, subject, msg, sentuserid, sent_time, upload_path, status) VALUES(integer,string,string,integer,string,string,integer);
```

Hope this helps to you !!

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
$newcomposeMail= '{"msg":"test mail","senderUserId":"1006","subject":"test","to":"10002"}';

$qryVal = json_decode($newcomposeMail,true);

//echo $qryVal->{'subject'};//here how you get json values

$qry ="INSERT INTO `push_msg_table`(`pid`, `subject`, `msg`, `sentuserid`, `sent_time`, `upload_path`, `status`) VALUES($pid,'".$qryVal->{'subject'}."','".$qryVal->{'msg'}."','".$qryVal->{'senderUserId'}."',.............";
```